# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, Cannot use UAS on external USB-3 connected disk array

Tags: usb-drive

**I recently purchased a 5-bay Orico disk Unit that I connected to my Ubuntu Server via Usb-3.
UAS was activated by default but caused a series a problems when doing Io intensive activities on any of the disks:**

```
Jan 26 12:27:24 HTPC kernel: [ 1448.712115] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.3: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 11 comp_code 1
Jan 26 12:27:24 HTPC kernel: [ 1448.713780] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.3: Looking for event-dma 00000003f9997aa0 trb-start* 00000003f9997ab0 trb-end 0000000000000000 seg-start 00000003f9997000 seg-end 00000003f9997ff0
Jan 26 12:27:24 HTPC kernel: [ 1448.713783] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.3: Looking for event-dma 00000003f9997aa0 trb-start 00000003f9996000 trb-end 00000003f99962b0 seg-start 00000003f9996000 seg-end 00000003f9996ff0
Jan 26 12:27:54 HTPC kernel: [ 1478.725405] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: OUT 
Jan 26 12:27:54 HTPC kernel: [ 1478.725411] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 0f 78 84 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
Jan 26 12:27:54 HTPC kernel: [ 1478.748995] scsi host11: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Jan 26 12:27:54 HTPC kernel: [ 1478.829618] usb 4-2.2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan 26 12:27:54 HTPC kernel: [ 1478.855944] scsi host11: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
Jan 26 12:27:55 HTPC kernel: [ 1479.234879] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sdd2-8
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.130565] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.130596] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.130600] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.130606] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#24 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 10 b2 80 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.130611] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdd, sector 280133632 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.475897] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.3: WARN Successful completion on short TX
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.475943] EXT4-fs warning (device sdd2): ext4_end_bio:309: I/O error 5 writing to inode 131072004 (offset 1040187392 size 8388608 starting block 35017728)
Jan 26 12:29:04 HTPC kernel: [ 1548.475947] buffer_io_error: 1256 callbacks suppressed*
```

Further to Google searches relating to similar problems, I Blacklisted UAS for the array:

```
options usb-storage quirks=2109:0715:u   in /etc/modprobe.d
```

Now works fine.

Am I losing speed ? Any way to circumvent problem. It seems to be a know issue of compatibility ...

Here is the Usbtree, showing usb-storage as driver, where used to be UAS

```
*/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M

|__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M

    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

    |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M

        |__ Port 3: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

        |__ Port 4: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M

|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M

|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M

    |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M

|__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M

|__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M

|__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M

/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M*
```

Comment: I think you have the correct fix. USB3 and UAS can cause problems. I have an ext USB3 500G SSD and a WD 320G and both had all kinds of weird disk errors until I disabled UAS.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. Any significant loss of performance ?

Comment: I don't believe so. It's better to have a working disk subsystem, than one that doesn't work at all. UAS is known to have issues.